# Since what Ubuntu version/release was created apt? Where is the official announce?

Tags: apt, package-management, blog

Since what Ubuntu version/release was created and available the `apt` command? It with the purpose to replace `apt-get` or offered how a new alternative against `apt-get`

I want the official post from `Ubuntu.com` indicating or announcing the "new" `apt` command, and the reason(s), ***it for historical documentation purposes***.

Yes, I read some tutorials about the difference between them and the reasons, but not from the source (`Ubuntu.com`)

Comment: It seems doubtful to me that an "*official post from Ubuntu.com*" exists. While several Ubuntu volunteers and several Canonical engineers have contributed to apt, and even had leadership roles with the apt project, it's an upstream project -- not an Ubuntu project, not a Canonical project. You can see this in the `apt` package control file: `Original-Maintainer: APT Development Team <deity@lists.debian.org>`. See https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Apt

Comment: Many blogs posted to ubuntu.com do not remain there...   I'm involved with *Ubuntu News* and we note blogs during the week, summaries are written on the weekend, but we always check just prior to posting as it's common for a Ubuntu blog that existed, to no longer exist (*thus we remove it too from our post prior to publish*).  If I was after dating details; I'd search old Ubuntu News weekly newsletter as if the article wasn't removed prior to publish time, we don't remove the links (*and it provides rather accurate dating too*) but I do agree with user535733

Comment: FYI:  A quick command on CLI and I can see`apt` is available for all *supported* releases of Ubuntu (including the ESM releases too!)  Alas *precise* (12.04) completed it's ESM so that no longer shows on my CLI enquiries (as they'll only show *supported* *development* + ESM)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - seems there are other "official" resources. But in some point and from some place that announce had been released for some Ubuntu specific, release, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, it will be difficult to locate an "official announcement" of the release of `apt`. Second, `apt` is not created by the Ubuntu developers. It is a formal part of the [APT package management](https://github.com/Debian/apt) system, maintained by Debian.

According to a [blog post](https://mvogt.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/apt-1-0/) of Michael Vogt, developper for Deban (since 2000) and Ubuntu (since 2004), the new tool `apt` was introduced along with APT 1.0, which was released on 1 april 2014. It was [included](https://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.6-desktop-amd64.manifest) in Ubuntu 14.04 (with thanks to muru) but only publicized in later versions.

Comment: `apt` is found in *trusty* repositories too; `apt | 1.0.1ubuntu2    | trusty          | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el`  (with later package versions in -updates etc) & you'll note the package on *trusty* manifests too - https://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.6-desktop-amd64.manifest  but older *unsupported* releases are harder to get facts than current...

Comment: I just downloaded *precise* (https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.manifest) & `apt` was included there too; `0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10`

Comment: @guiverc do those packages contain the `apt` command, though? I looked through the Docker images of the old releases and the oldest in which I can see an `apt` binary is 14.04, which makes sense since it was [first added to the `apt` repo around 2013 (version 0.9.11)](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/commit/b917917067e757c4479a344a263ef7cf43c00866).

Comment: @muru I'd have to grab them & look as changelogs, package.contains.lists etc. are harder to see on non-supported releases (inc. with ESM); even if some CLI tools we include ESM releases such as *trusty*.  `trusty` is as far as I can see backwards for it too; but I don't have a *trusty* system to confirm & don't care enough to create one & confirm.  I believe it existed before *xenial* but wasn't very good & most of us just ignored it...

Comment: +1 great research that seems to clearly and directly answer the question.

Comment: About _"It was included in Ubuntu 14.04 (with thanks to muru) but only publicized in later versions"_ - is normal such approach? To be honest and without be rude is assumed at a first glance that it should be had announced from the beginning - 14.04