# What's the difference between `apt search <package-name>` and `apt-cache search <package-name>`?

Tags: apt, package-management, search, apt-cache

When searching for packages in the apt repository we can use `apt search <package-name>` and `apt-cache search <package-name>` inside the terminal and we get a list of package names matching `<package-name>` with both the commands. Two questions -

1. What's the major difference between the two commands?
2. When to use which command over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt` is a more recent tool, combining functionality of the older tools `apt-get`, `apt-cache`, etc., and is aimed to be more optimized for interactive use.

Both `apt search` and `apt-cache search` serve to retrieve package names that fulfill a search criterion.

`apt-cache search` by default lists package name and short description on a single name:

```
~$ apt-cache search xvile 
vile - VI Like Emacs - vi work-alike
vile-common - VI Like Emacs - support files for vile/xvile
vile-filters - VI Like Emacs - highlighting filters for vile/xvile
xvile - VI Like Emacs - vi work-alike (X11)
```

`apt` also provides version information and architecture, in a two line format:

```
~$ apt search xvile
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
vile/jammy 9.8v-1build1 amd64
  VI Like Emacs - vi work-alike

vile-common/jammy,jammy 9.8v-1build1 all
  VI Like Emacs - support files for vile/xvile

vile-filters/jammy 9.8v-1build1 amd64
  VI Like Emacs - highlighting filters for vile/xvile

xvile/jammy 9.8v-1build1 amd64
  VI Like Emacs - vi work-alike (X11)
```

only searches package name and description. With the option provides a compact list of package name and description

With the `--full` option, `apt-search` provides full package info for all found packages:

```
~$ apt-cache search xvile --full
Package: vile
Architecture: amd64
Version: 9.8v-1build1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/editors
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Brendan O'Dea <bod@debian.org>
```

...information that with `apt`, can be retrieved with the `show` command for individual packages:

```
~$ apt show xvile
Package: xvile
Version: 9.8v-1build1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/editors
Source: vile
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Brendan O'Dea <bod@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 1,509 kB
```

`apt-cache search` can be made to search package names only with the `--names-only` option:

```
~$ apt-cache search xvile --names-only 
xvile - VI Like Emacs - vi work-alike (X11)
```

*Which one to use?*

In principle, `apt` is developed specifically to be your more simple day-to-day interactive tool, but ultimately the choice is yours. All of these APT tools will [continue to be around](https://askubuntu.com/a/1412069/558158).